# How to check if a cell is selected in Powerbuilder datawindow object?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am trying to implement a copy/paste feature in a datawindow.  User will be able to select the cells using mouse.  My first step is to identify which row-column pairs are selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the answer, it's just that we don't have a specific example.

We can use selected property on the datawindow object.

```
string setting
setting = dw1.Object.DataWindow.Selected
```

The resulted string will have a syntax of

```
1stRow/lastRow/Column1{/Column2...}
```

For example, if you only select 1 cell, it will look like

```
5/5/name --> this means you selected row 5 on column "name"
```

If you select horizontally on a row, it will look like

```
3/3/firstname/lastname/address --> this means you selected cells on row 3 and on columns 'firstname', 'lastname', and 'address'
```

If you select vertically on a column, it will look like

```
3/7/age --> this means you selected cells on column 'age', from row 3 to 7
```

If you select in a rectangle shape, it will look like

```
3/7/fname/lname --> this means you selected cells on columns 'fname' and 'lname', from row 3 to 7
```

I hope this post helps other developer looking for this.